# why my CSS transition not working in react

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

My css transition not working correctly

when I click the button, the `div` disappears immediately...

I had tried animation too.

But when the animation finishes, the width becomes 0 immediately.

react

```
const NaviDrawer = ({ naviData, show }) => {
    return (
        <div className={`navi container${show ? " show" : " hide"}`}>
            {naviData.map((item, index) => {
                return item.initIdentity === permissionTypes.ADMIN ? (
                    <AdminNaviItem key={item.id} id={item.id} path={item.path} />
                ) : (
                    <UserNaviItem key={item.id} id={item.id} path={item.path} />
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};
```

css

```
.navi.container {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: calc(100% - 70px);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: width 2s linear;
    transition: width 2s linear;
}

.navi.container.hide {
    width: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: width 2s linear;
    transition: width 2s linear;
}
```

Comment: You're missing space `className={`navi container ${show ? " show" : " hide"}`}`

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to have the `transition` parameter in the css rule for the initial state, so just erase `transition: width 2s linear;` and similar (prefixed versions) from  `.navi.container.hide`